# how can I import library file to IntelliJ? without maven

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I want to make a simple JavaEE application without maven. How can I do if I want to add a library to it ( no dependencies)? I tried it, but cant find an exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

open "Open Module Setting " of the project.((view > Open Project Module)).
Select Library in left side . Then add library in the your hard drive by clicking "+